# CSRF token is not being verified

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-1.8

I have a form:

```
<form action="{% url "some_url" %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text">Text Input
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Which is being submitted via AJAX:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
});
```

The URL routes to this view:

```
class SomeView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = dict(**some_data)
        rendered_html = render_to_string('some_template.html', context, RequestContext(self.request))
        return JsonResponse(dict(html=rendered_html))
```

All this works. The problem is that it also works when the CSRF token is not sent, I am getting the exact same successful response:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

I would expect some kind of error to be raised because the CSRF token is missing.

To state the obvious: `CsrfViewMiddleware` is within `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Explicitly using `csrf_token` has the same result when the token is not sent:

```
method_decorator(csrf_protect)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(SomeView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

What can I do to enforce its verification?

Comment: Do you have a custom `MIDDLEWARE` setting? Can you confirm that `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` is active? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it

Comment: @HåkenLid as I said, it is in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`. Is there any way I could check at runtime if it is indeed active, just to make sure? (if it weren't active to begin with, I am sure `{% csrf_token %}` would output an empty string, but I am getting an actual token.

Comment: @dabadaba maybe the CSRF token is sent in cookie. So no matter what you post the cookies will be sent to the server. Read here for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/

Comment: Try with a new incognito window, or use the browser devtools to inspect cookies. I think the csrf cookie is set if you have visited any page that uses the `{% csrf_token %}` in the current browser session. Cookies is included with the `jQuery.post` request, and accepted by the csrf middleware.

Comment: That's it, the token is sent in a cookie. You guys can post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The cookie is just one part. It also has to be send in the form data or in the `X-CsrfToken` header before `CsrfViewMiddleware` would allow the response. Does it still work when you use `curl -X POST <url>` to access the url?

Comment: @knbk No, it did not work. I got a 403 response and the reason for failure is "CSRF cookie not set." I guess it is working then, and the others were right about the token being sent in a cookie :)

Comment: I suspect you have some javascript that automatically sets the header on AJAX requests.

Comment: @knbk which means I should probably keep using `{% csrf_token %}` as usual, just in case, right?

Comment: `{% csrf_token %}` triggers Django to set the cookie, which is required for that code to work, so yes.

Comment: Please, anybody, post an answer with the cookie stuff and I will accept it. I don't want to leave this unanswered. @norbert.mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dabadaba maybe the CSRF token is sent in cookie. So no matter what you post the cookies will be sent to the server. Read here for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/

Comment: Django uses the [Double Submit Cookie pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie) to protect against CSRF attacks. Simply having the CSRF token sent in a cookie is _not_ enough to get around the `CsrfViewMiddleware`. The same token needs to be present in the cookie **and** in either the POST body or the `X-CsrfToken` header.

Answer (score 0):

### An Intro

There are a variety of CSRF protection patterns well explained in the OWASP [cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).

#### Django CSRF Protection

Django uses the Double Submit Cookie pattern. It is simple to implement (compare to interaction-based patterns like Captcha) and more important: It is the recommended pattern for stateless services like RESTful APIs.

How does it work?

Assume the **sensitive service** as the service has a vulnerability in terms of CSRF attack and you want to make it secure.

The client gets aware of the CSRF token before calling the sensitive service either by:

- an HTML injected value in the server-side rendered HTML files
- a cookie that is sent to the client in the previous services named CSRF-token
  The token is secure-random and is not the same as the authentication token.

So the client must include the CSRF token in two fields (so that it is called double submit cookie), two examples:

1. submit it in both forms hidden input field and the CSRF cookie header
2. submit it in both `X-CSRF-TOKEN` custom header and the CSRF cookie header

So Django CSRF middleware will just check if both tokens are submitted and equal or not.

> Note that it is assumed that the hacker is not able to run javascript code at the client's browser to submit the values. This vulnerability must be defended in terms of XSS attack prevention.

To check you can implement the Django framework's solution check the document [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/). especially check these sections:

#### For stateless services:

```py
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def the_previous_called_service_sending_the_csrf_cookie(request):
    # the implementation
    return response

@csrf_protect
def the_sensitive_service(request):
    # the implementation
    return response
```

#### for stateful services (ex server-side rendered forms):

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!--- other form fields --->
</form>
```

#### Warning!

Enabling the `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in Django settings file is not enough for the stateless approach. You must also set the `@csrf_protect` decorator too. So don't be satisfied with just enabling the middleware. I don't know why the awesome Django guys do not mention this point in [this documentation version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/) explicitly as it causes the performance overhead without any protection and I think it is a source of confusion. Anyway!

###### You can test and make sure the protection is done with a code like this:

```py
def test_sensitive_service_should_fail_without_csrf_header(self):
    csrf_client = APIClient(enforce_csrf_checks=True,)
    csrf_client.force_authenticate(self.user1)
        response = csrf_client.post("path/to/sensitive/service",
        format="json",
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)


def test_sensitive_service_should_succeed_with_csrf_header(self):

    csrf_client = APIClient(enforce_csrf_checks=True)
    csrf_client.force_authenticate(self.user1)
    data = {"my_field": "my_value"}
    # service to get csrf token before calling sensitive service
    auth_response = self.client.post(
        "/path/to/prior/service", data=data, format="json", follow=True
    )
    csrf_client.cookies = auth_response.cookies
    csrf_token = auth_response.cookies["csrftoken"]
    # calling sensitive service with appropriate csrf token header
    response = csrf_client.put("/path/to/sensitive/service/",
        format="json",
        HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN=csrf_token.value,
        secure=True,
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTP_200_OK)
```

*Also, I give the credit to @knbk to point to this note first in the comments.*